# create consistant department name and code

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I have a department model in django:

```
from django.db import models

class Departement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3, db_index=True)
```

I'd like to create a fixture with factory_boy with a consistent department name and code.

Faker has a `department` provider which returns a tuple with the code and the department (ex for french: https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/locales/fr_FR.html#faker.providers.address.fr_FR.Provider.department)

I have created a `DepartmentFixture` class but fail to understand how to use an instance of faker to call the `faker.derpartments()` method then populate the code/name fields accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I gues [factory.Faker()](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=Faker#factory.Faker) is what you are searching for

```
import factory
from myapp.models import Departement

class DepartmentFixture(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Departement

    class Params:
        department_tuple = factory.Faker('department')
    
    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: obj.department_tuple[1])
    code = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: obj.department_tuple[0])
```

Comment: `factory.Faker('department')` return a tuple, with the department code (which, if I take France as an example, is a number) and the name. I'd like to insert the name and the code so the `Department`model generated by the fixture has a consistent state between the code and the name.

Comment: `Departement() got an unexpected keyword argument 'department_tuple'` :-/

Comment: You can try to set it in [class Params](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html?highlight=LazyAttribute#altering-a-factory-s-behavior-parameters-and-traits)

Answer (score 0):

Following @weAreStarsDust I finally make this work:

```
import factory
from myapp.models import Departement

class DepartmentFixture(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Departement

    class Params:
        department = factory.Faker('department')

    name = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda d: d.department_tuple[1])
    code = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda d: d.department_tuple[0])
```